# Second return statement nested in if statement

Tags: java, string, return, guard, clause

I am wondering what `return str.substring(1,4).equals("bad");` is doing here  in the `else if(len>=4)`. I think the if statement is a guard clause but I am not 100%. Can I have an explanation of what exactly is going on here? How is this read to output "false"?

Given a string, return true if "bad" appears starting at index 0 or 1 in the string, such as with "badxxx" or "xbadxx" but not "xxbadxx". The string may be any length, including 0. Note: use .equals() to compare 2 strings.

hasBad("badxx") → true

hasBad("xbadxx") → true

hasBad("xxbadxx") → false

```
public boolean hasBad(String str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    if(len == 3 && str.equals("bad"))
        return true;
    else if(len >= 4)
    {
        if(str.substring(0, 3).equals("bad"))
            return true;
        return str.substring(1, 4).equals("bad");
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: You want to know what `return str.substring(1, 4).equals("bad");` does?

Comment: If you have no idea what this code does, why don't you ask the person who wrote it why the code is written the way it is.  note: This is the same as `return str.matches(".?bad.*");`

Answer (score 2):

`if(str.substring(0, 3).equals("bad"))` is the easy part. "Return true if 'bad' is the beginning of the `String`.'

`return str.substring(1, 4).equals("bad")` essentially means, "Return true if 'bad' occurs after the first character, and false otherwise". This is basically a shortcut of

```
if(str.substring(1, 4).equals("bad")) return true;
else return false;
```

Because the `if` already evaluates a boolean (what goes inside of an if results in a boolean value), there's no reason to tell it to return "true if true, else false", you can just return the boolean value directly.

Comment: And boom goes the dynamite. Thanks for the explanation, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it in other way too, like below one

```
public static boolean hasBad(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {

        if (str.length()>=3 && str.charAt(0) == 'b' || str.charAt(1) == 'b' ) {

            if (str.substring(i).contains("bad")) {

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```